# How to workaround conflict between greek and titlecaps?

Tags: babel, greek, titlecaps

I need to load `greek` with `babel` to support Greek text, but I am also using `titlecaps` to capitalise certain heading text.

Unfortunately, it seems this combination is not compatible but I'm having trouble identifying the specific cause and figuring out a workaround.

```
\documentclass[greek,british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\Addlcwords{of}

\begin{document}

    This is some text.

\end{document}
```

What is the best way to adapt this code so that it works properly?

In the example above, commenting out `\Addlcwords{of}` gets the code to compile. However, in my real example, this just results in a different error later in the code, and so on. So I'm pretty sure there is something systematic I'm doing wrong here. What is it?

Comment: I will submit a revised package with egreg's recommendations, once I can fully understand the extent of the issues.  I have already worked up the `\roman` fix, but I'm trying to understand his comment about unprotected end-of-lines.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's wonderful! Thank you! I look forward to trying it out.

Comment: I just uploaded titlecaps V1.2 to ctan.  It incorporates the bug fixes suggested by egreg.  I also figured out how to handle `\l` and `\aa` which had eluded me earlier.  It may take a day or two to propagate.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Brilliant! You should post that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: egreg deserves all the credit.  Please accept his answer.  If you want, I can post *an* answer once the upgrade propagates, just to let readers know more easily that the fix is instituted in the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the usual problem: the package uses `\roman` for representing a counter value in roman numerals, but the `greek` option to `babel` changes `\roman` into a non fully expandable command.

Unfortunately, `\roman` is used in almost all macros of `titlecaps`, so providing a patch means rewriting the package.

The workaround suggested by Manuel in comments *may* work, but it can break Greek text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@roman\@roman
\makeatother

\usepackage[greek,british]{babel}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\makeatletter
\let\@roman\latex@roman
\makeatother

\Addlcwords{of}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

\end{document}
```

As a side note: the `titlecaps` package needs to be revised anyway, because several of its macros have unprotected end-of-lines in the definitions.

A series of patches to the commands of `titlecaps` that should give the right behavior seems to be as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[greek,british]{babel}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\dopatch#1{\xpatchcmd{#1}{\roman}{\romannumeral\value}{}{}}
\dopatch\Addlcwords
\dopatch\add@lcword
\dopatch\seek@lcwords
\dopatch\seek@lcwords
\dopatch\seek@lcwords
\dopatch\seek@lcwords
\dopatch\titlecap
\dopatch\titlecap
\dopatch\titlecap
\dopatch\titlecap
\dopatch\titlecap
\dopatch\titlecap
\dopatch\title@string
\dopatch\title@string
\dopatch\title@string
\dopatch\parse@@@Block
\undef\dopatch
\makeatother

\Addlcwords{of}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

\end{document}
```

In this way all occurrences of `\roman{<counter>}` are changed into `\romannumeral\value{<counter>}` which is safe, because it expands to `\romannumeral\c@<counter>` and the search for a number ends there.

### Update

With `titlecaps` version 1.2, released 2015/01/30, the issues have been solved and your original example will work unchanged.

Comment: `\let\originalroman\roman` before `babel` and the other way after loading `babel` package?

Comment: @Manuel This could be a solution provided `\roman` is never used for Greek text, which might be a safe assumption, but it depends on the nature of the document.

Comment: Thanks and thanks @Manuel. However, I'm not sure this is going to work in my case... Hmm...

Comment: Is there any alternative to `titlecaps`? I have a horrible feeling that I'm going to get into deep trouble with this solution.

Comment: @cfr I don't know what you're using it for. For me, capitalization is something to be left to the Germans. By the way, I found a copy of Jonathan Swift's *A Modest Proposal*, typeset with capitalized names in German style (which was used at Swift's time). But the font used is Times! It's really funny.

Comment: I used it in a timeline to automate the creation of nodes e.g. I tell it `aristotle` and it will create various things using `aristotle` while making it `Aristotle` when it gets typeset. (I don't like having to type capital letters.) But it isn't always a single name, of course. (See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/215082#215082.)

Comment: Thank you [again] for this diagnosis.  I will submit a revised version with the `\roman` -> `\romannumeral\value` correction.  What do you mean by an unprotected end-of-line?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm referring to lines 205 and 209, where a line inside a definition is not protected with `%` and it should be. Also, after any assignment such as ``\catcode`~=13``, leave a space or end-of-line.

Comment: @egreg.  Oops on the missing `%`.  I should have seen those.  I was unaware of the rule regarding use of `\catcode` and a trailing space.  Does that comment apply equally well to the two occurrences within `\def\get@argsC#1`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes. While ``\catcode`~=12\fi`` does no real harm, because `\fi` is followed by `\protected@edef` that, in turn, starts with `\let`, it's better avoiding premature expansions and ``\catcode`~=12 \fi`` is the best method. The `%` after the final 13 will cause again premature expansion when `\get@argsC` is expanded and the `\catcode` assignment is performed.