# Memoir, Babel, and indices

Tags: memoir, imakeidx, bibleref

So strange problem. Below is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel} %greek typesetting
\usepackage{bibleref}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

%\AtBeginDocument{\shorthandoff{:}}
\makeindex

\frontmatter
\begin{document}
   Test verse citation. \ibibleverse{John}(3:16)     
\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This currently fails to produce an index. It works if I either turn off the `babel` package, or remove the `\frontmatter` command. Looking at the generated `.idx` file, the difference is that instead of `{i}` or `{1}` appended to the end of the entry (the page number), a `{\textlatin  {i}}` is appended, and this causes it to reject the entry. As can be seen by my commented out line, I tried de-activating the colon character in case that was somehow doing it but that didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's not the colon, but the fact that with `greek.polutoniko` the macro `\roman` is redefined and its output becomes unsuitable for usage with `makeindex`.

Comment: Hmm, so is there no hope then? I'm not particularly tied down to `makeindex` that I know of, maybe I'll try `xindy`.

Comment: There may be workarounds; the simplest, in my opinion, is not using Roman numbers for the front matter. Or, if you're sure you don't need Roman numbers in a Greek context, restoring the definition of `\roman` to the standard one.

Comment: Thanks. I don't intend on using Roman numbers in the Greek so your solution from this [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225434/how-to-workaround-conflict-between-greek-and-titlecaps) worked.